# I can't cope with custom action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Tasks controller I have action:

```
  def destroy_all
    current_user.tasks.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

My db schema looks like below:

```
  create_table "tasks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.boolean  "done"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "users_id"
  end
```

And I have relation: Tasks belongs_to User and User has_many Tasks.
By action `destory_all` I want to destroy all current user's tasks.

But when I click:

```
<%= link_to "delete all", { controller: 'tasks', action: 'destroy_all'}, method: 'delete' %>
```

Nothing happen. User still have all his tasks.

Log from server console:

```
Started DELETE "/tasks/destroy_all" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-04 23:29:27 +0200
Processing by TasksController#destroy_all as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"fVPDi6bczNXlfhjCDI4pJhMUm3cjv6TN1Ny/ulUO4YQ="}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-04 23:29:27 +0200
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."done" = 'f' AND "tasks"."user_id" = 2
  Rendered tasks/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_userbar.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 46ms (Views: 44.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

And routes.rb file

```
  resources :tasks do
    collection do
      delete :destroy_all
    end
  end
```

EDIT: I updated log and link_to method and I added routes.rb file.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors or warnings in your logs?

Comment: No errors I can recognize. I added log snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your task table needs the field "user_id", not "users_id". This will probably fix your problem right away.

However, you're missing the power of *has_many*!  Just do this:

```
current_user.tasks.destroy_all
```

Calling "current_user.tasks" gets a list of the user's task for you, and you can then call "destroy" on them as I did above. This is cleaner and easier to read.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for advice about _has_many_ power but it haven't fixed my problem. It is still the same. I changed `users_id` for `user_id`. I click 'delete_all' link and nothing happen. Server log is the same too.

Comment: The server log won't be *exactly* the same, because the table has changed. At the very least, the field name will be different. Maybe you should post the updated log data.

Comment: Your log snippet is for a home page request, so Rails isn't hitting your delete_all action at all. What code is your "link_to" method generating?

Comment: Like this: `<a href="/tasks/destroy_all?method=delete">delete all</a>`

Comment: Your link_to needs to look like this: `<%= link_to 'delete all', {controller: 'tasks', action: 'destroy_all'}, method: 'delete' %>`. Note the curly brackets around the 2nd parameter. The method has to be specified in the *third* parameter, which most people don't know about.

Comment: Hmm I thought you meant the link generated by browser. My link is all the time in the post and looks like: `<%= link_to "delete all", controller: 'tasks', action: 'destroy_all', method: 'delete' %>`. Is there any mistake? Aren't curly braces optional?

Comment: @Jensky link_to has *three* parameters, not two. First is the text that will be displayed. The second is a hash of the route it will go to. The third is a hash of extra options. The `:method` option goes in the *third* parameter. Since the last two parameters are both hashes, you have to use curly brackets around the second parameter so Ruby knows where one ends and the next begins.

Comment: Thank you again. I repaired this. But it's still not working. I've also updated log info, action body and link_to method code. Can you look at updated log?

Comment: The method you need is `current_user.tasks.destroy_all`, not `current_user.tasks.destroy`, my mistake. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Of course, I'm a bit tired. Now works perfect. Tank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

According to your schema, `users_id` is a `String` which might be `"1"` or `"2"`. But the `current_user.id` is `Integer` which might be `1` or `2`.

In this case, you will find nothing in your ActiveRecord because it queries for items that id is a string, which you actually send an integer.

Thus try:

`Task.destroy_all(users_id: current_user.id.to_s)`

to match the type.

==============================

However, your structure is complicated and it will be hard to maintain in the future. I suggest you do the following:

1. In `Task` model, change `users_id` to `user_id` because it only belongs to a single user.
2. Changer the type of the `user_id` to integer because it is `id`, and logically it only contains numeric value.
3. As Jaime suggests, make use of rails convention in `has_many` and write something like `current_user.tasks.delete_all` to keep your code clean and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for a really helpful advise but it isn't the main problem. Because I have destroy action and it works OK. Of course I tried your solution but nothing changed. Maybe you know how can I debug this to get more information about the problem?

Comment: Try specify a method in the link cause it is GET by default `<%= link_to "delete all", controller: 'tasks', action: 'destroy_all', method: :delete %>`

Comment: With this approach you have to modify your `route.rb` and make sure the `:destroy_all` is something like `collection { delete :destroy_all }` or there will be a routing error

Comment: While it's not a good idea to store id's as strings, ActiveRecord does the cleanup for you and builds the query correctly. This is why a route like "/users/123" will result in params[:id] = "123", a string, but User.find(params[:id]) still works.

Comment: I've just tried change `get` to `delete` and I edited my post. It is still not working.